# OpenCL - Draw image and zoom into it

Tags: image, 2d, zooming, opencl, draw

I'm trying to draw an image directly to the screen. The is calculated by a kernel and will be stored in the GPU-memory, so it should not be copied back to the CPU-Memory. It should also be possible to dynamically zoom into the image while calculating more data at the same time.

Can anyone point me to a method that does this effectively? Everything I've found so far was incredibly slow (for example using OpenGL to draw a cube with the image as texture). What is the fastest way to achieve this? Like I said, while zooming into the image, it should be possible to calculate more data to refine the image dynamically. From what I've read, OpenGL might be the fastest way (performance-wise) but it seems incredibly slow to me to put the image on a cube and run a ton of shaders over it if it's already the way I want it.

Mathe172

Answer (score 0):

Find one of the many OpenCL / OpenGL interop examples, they all show what you want. They create an OpenCL image made to interop with an OpenGL texture, and after rendering OpenCL data into the image they display it using OpenGL -- no copy back to CPU memory over the PCIe bus. The zooming into the image can be done just by scaling up the OpenGL quad that you draw the texture onto. If you are talking lots of scaling, then you will need a high-resolution texture. If lots and lots of zooming you should rethink the problem and compute just what you need for the current display (since with lots of zoom, plenty of data will be off-screen).

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. How exactly would I render the texture? As I said, all examples I found used a cube to render the texture, which seems very inefficient to me... Also, is there any way to tell OpenGL not to use all the GPU-time? Like I said, I want to calculate a better image while scaling

Comment: You don't have to render anything fancy with the texture, just a quad would be sufficient. Some of the interop examples do exactly that. Then OpenGL uses very little of the GPU (make sure to limit it to vsync rate so you are not over-drawing).